# What do you call honey harvested by beekeepers?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary, food

There are kinds of honey called *forest honey*, *cliff honey*, *dwarf honey* etc.

What is honey farmed by beekeepers called?

Comment: Just honey. You wouldn't normally qualify it. That said, beekeepers keep bees near all sorts of flowers, so that can change the type of honey.

Comment: Local honey, beekeeper's honey or unblended honey. Commercially distributed honey is almost always blended from the produce of, not only many hives but also from hives owned by many people. A lot of it is even blended from honey from a number of different contries.

Comment: There's an example on the internet stating "I don't have an answer whether wild honey or farmed honey is better." One might think that [benefits-of-honey.com](https://www.benefits-of-honey.com/wild-honey.html), a dedicated website, should know the terminology.

Comment: Isn't almost all honey made by beekeepers? I thought you were onto something with the summary of your question (*homemade honey* perhaps*), but then got confused by your final sentence. So, what are you actually asking?

Answer (score 2):

The *cultivation* of bees for honey is called [bee culture](https://archive.org/details/texts?and[]=honey&sin=&and[]=subject%3A%22Bee%20culture%20Periodicals%22) or sometimes [honey culture](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.263198/2015.263198.Japan-Reborn#page/n145/mode/2up/search/honey+culture), and honey harvested from cultivated beehives is called [***cultivated honey***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cultivated%20honey&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccultivated%20honey%3B%2Cc0).

Sources: *Archive.org* and *Ngram Viewer*.

According to *Apiculture* ("bee and honey culture"), by Gurghen Artashesovich Avetisyan (c.1978):

> There are both *wild honey* plants and [*cultivated honey*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ye1JAAAAYAAJ&q=%22cultivated%20honey%22&dq=%22cultivated%20honey%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_rqOZoOvbAhVkjK0KHdybAu8Q6AEIPDAD) crops...

And according to *Wikipedia*:

> [Honey was also *cultivated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey) in ancient Mesoamerica.

Also, *Etymonline* states that the term, apiculture (honeybee culture), is from the analogy with [*agriculture*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/apiculture). Thus, cultivation.